# Cloud Document AI can't process documents from storage

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I have the following code:

```
const client = new DocumentProcessorServiceClient();

const inputConfig = {
    mimeType: 'application/pdf',
    gcsSource: {
        uri: gcsSourceUri,
    },
};
const outputConfig = {
    gcsDestination: {
        uri: gcsDestinationUri,
    },
};
const name = `projects/myproject/locations/us/processors/myprocessor`;
const request = {
    name,
    inputConfigs: [inputConfig],
    outputConfig: outputConfig
};

async function getText() {
    const [operation] = await client.batchProcessDocuments(request);
};

getText();
```

Which produces the following error:

```
(node:72144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to process all the documents
    at Operation._unpackResponse (E:\development\audiobook\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\longRunningCalls\longrunning.js:136:31)
    at E:\development\audiobook\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\longRunningCalls\longrunning.js:122:18
(node:72144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:72144) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What might be the problem here? The Cloud Storage URI is working and the file is in the correct format.

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there any way to get at least more information about the error?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the format of outputConfig.

Checking your code I found you are defining the outputConfig this way:

```
const outputConfig = {
    gcsDestination: {
        uri: gcsDestinationUri,
    },
};
```

while according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta3/projects.locations.processors/batchProcess)  you should change it into

```
 const outputConfig = {
        gcsDestination: {
            gcsDestinationUri: 'gs://bucket-name/folder/',
        },
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65826292/6216983 is correct for `v1beta3`

For the GA version `v1`, you can find the updated request structure in the documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#documentai_process_document-nodejs